# ACF field Groups not showing on wp-admin

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I have a website where only 9 out of 25 fields groups are visible on the wp-admin. There is a folder (in theme folder) with all of them in JSON format. I would like to remove this folder and move all of the fields to wp-admin.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to import the JSON files using the ACF import option?

Comment: Yes, it looks like some of the code in the theme doing this. When I swapped to standard 2021 all is good.